# if(fp != EOF) -> Warning: Comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, pointers, integer, comparison, warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;

   char written[]= "This is not as easy as I thought it would be.";
    fp = fopen("Aufgabe 3.txt", "w");
    if(fp != EOF)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s", written);
        printf("Text was written!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File can not be found!");
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I am new to coding and need a little help. :D

Does anyone know how to get rid of the warning, I simply want to write a sentence into a .txt .

Warning in line: 10 `if(fp != EOF)`:

> *comparison between pointer and integer*

Comment: Try using `if(fp != NULL)` to check whether opening the file was successful

Comment: `fp` === file pointer. Now connect the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EOF` is a macro for a negative integer constant. `fp` is a pointer to `FILE`.

If you use

```
if (fp != EOF)
```

you compare a pointer with an integer of a non-zero value, which isn't permissible.

Replace `EOF` with `NULL` which is a macro to check for errors with pointers:

```
if (fp != NULL)
```

---

Side Notes:

- Also you should only use `fclose()` on a pointer to a stream which was successfully opened. If you use `flose(fp)` if `fp` is `NULL`, the program has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984).
- Furthermore with `if (fp != NULL)` you check if the opening of the stream was *without* errors and continue then into the `if`s body when the opening of the stream to the file was successful. Else if the opening was not successful you go into the `else` body.

  This code can be simplified.

  Simply check whether an error occurred and if yes flow through an error routine in the `if`'s body. If not, The control flow immediately continues to the code in `main()` after the `if` statement. No need for an `else`.
- Your error routine should be enhanced in production code. Just printing out that the opening of the file wasn't successful isn't enough.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    FILE *fp;

    char written[] = "This is not as easy as I thought it would be.";

    fp = fopen("Aufgabe 3.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(fp, "%s", written);
    printf("Text was written!\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`fopen` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) returns a pointer to the newly opened file stream or, on error, a `NULL` pointer (which is ***not*** the same as the `EOF` *integer* constant). Use this, instead:

```c
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%s", written);
        printf("Text was written!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File can not be found!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable *fp* is a pointer so you should compare it with NULL, not EOF which is an integer (see the reference documentation for *fopen*: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Also

1. you should write a newline character to the file (in order for it to be a text file)
2. errors should be printed to the standard error stream
3. it's a good idea to print the cause of why opening the file failed
4. the program should exit with an error code upon failure
5. the call to *fclose* should only be made if opening the file was successful
6. since the variable *written* is not modified it can be turned into a pointer constant.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *filename = "Aufgabe 3.txt";
    const char *written = "This is not as easy as I thought it would be.";
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", written);
        printf("Text was written!\n");
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opening file '%s' failed: %s:\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```